# scss и :hover не могу нормально использывать

Tags: css, scss, hover

когда я пишу в scss такой код

```
a {
    border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-right: 34px;

    :hover {
        transition: 0.3s;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
}
```

он переводит в css это так

```
.wrapper .container .concontainer .navbar a :hover {  transition: 0.3s;border: 3px solid #fff;border-radius: 30px;}
```

а если в ручную убрать  пробел между **а и :hover** все заработает
в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Должно выглядеть вот так: `a:hover { ... }`, а сейчас, если скомпилировать, то получается вот так: `a > :hover { ... }`. Используйте `&`, чтобы указать `a:hover`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так нужно:

```
&:hover { ...
```

Comment: огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @TigranVardanyan отметьте ответ как принятый.